# Update Rows after .Delete in TableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, delete-row, editing

Good day!

I have a TableViewController with EditingStyle:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .delete {
        machine.formulas.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        machine.saveFormulas()
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        tableView.reloadData()

    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }
}
```

Each cell has a label with row number. If i .reloadData() as in the code above it breaks the .deleteRows() animation. I tried different variations, with beginUpdates() and .reloadRows(), nothing gave the required result. I think there is a simple solution for that, but I can't figure it out.

**EDIT:**

Edited code so the item is removed from array at first then from tableView.

**EXAMPLE:**

[image]

If you delete row #5, how do you .reloadData() so everything is in order. I mean there won't be 1-2-3-4-6-7-8-9-10. And how do you reload it without breaking .Delete animation?

Comment: Why using `.reloadData()`? Only `.deleteRows` will do that for you. Also remove data from array first then delete the row from table.

Comment: Each cell has a label with row number. After TableView does it animation on removing a row, one disappear and all others move together the information on the rows themselves don't get updated.

Comment: Are you sing any array for tableView Data ?  if yes  you need to delete element from array too.

Answer (score 2):

just remove `tableView.reloadData()` from your code, It is not needed.
Your overridden method should be

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: 
    UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {    
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            machine.formulas.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            machine.saveFormulas()
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)            
        } else if editingStyle == .insert {
            // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
        }
    }
```

Comment: you have not specified any other actions besides deleting a row in your question, for deleting there is no need to call reloadData(). If you want to achieve any other things please edit your question so that we know what you want

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove from the dataSource and Delete the row can do, No need to reload it.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .delete {
    machine.formulas.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    machine.saveFormulas()
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    self.perform(#selector(reloadTable), with: nil, afterDelay: 2)

    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
    // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }
}

@objc func reloadTable() {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Try and share results.

**EDIT:**

You should update your cellForRow method to set the value based on indexPath and not from the numbersArray

because, initially numberArray has all 10 values. 
**1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10**
Now if you remove one row from 4rth row, then that specific value is being removed from the array and keeping 9 items i.e **1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10** and will see them in cells. Instead you should update your cellForRow to show indexPath.row + 1 for it.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1)"
    return cell
}
```

Hope it clears.

Comment: Animation is fine, but still rows are not updated after delete. 

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVClM.png

Comment: What you mean by "but still rows are not updated after delete" ?, you can see in the screenshot, the right image has one less row and it's deleted row with title b. can you explain, what else you are looking for?

Comment: Each row has a label with row number. Left side of each cell. They don't get updated, they used to be 1-2-3-4, then 2 row gets deleted, and they still go as 1-3-4 instead of 1-2-3

Comment: deleting rows, simply removes one row from the index, it will not reload the rows. You should reload the table in place of delete a single row, to get the required results.

Comment: That is what I am asking, since .deleteRows does not have any completion handler, how can i track its animation to be finished so i can .ReloadRows without interrupting?

Comment: it's clear now from your explanation, what you are looking for. checkout my edits. You may set the interval as required, I set it to 2 in perform selector method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178847/discussion-between-bhavin-kansagara-and-konstantin).

Comment: @Konstantin does it helped? Have you tried my latest edits?

Answer (score 0):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

if editingStyle == .delete {
    machine.formulas.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    machine.saveFormulas()
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    self.perform(#selector(reloadTable), with: nil, afterDelay: 2)

}
```

}

```
@objc func reloadTable() {
      DispatchQueue.main.async { //please do all interface updates in main thread only
      self.tableView.reloadData()
```

}
    }

Comment: I does trigger tableView.reloadData() but rows don't update. https://github.com/kmishukov/TableViewTest

Comment: please make the following changes

1.   var numbersArray: NSMutableArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

2.

if editingStyle == .delete {
            numbersArray.remove(indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            self.perform(#selector(reloadTable), with: nil, afterDelay: 1)
        }

Comment: let me know if any issue occures, else please give upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the item from the array, delete the row, then reload the TableView after using a completion handler:

So create this method (Swift 5):

```
func deleteRow(atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath, completion: () -> Void) {
    self.dataArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    completion()
}
```

And then call it like this wherever you need it:

```
func clearDataItem(atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
    deleteRow(atIndexPath: indexPath) {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```